# PHP don't execute batch file using exec

Tags: php, batch-file

I'm trying to execute a command in PHP

Here's the command

```
c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /b START C:\xampp2\htdocs\barcodeprinting\test\printbarcode.bat
```

I also tried other commands like

```
system('cmd /c C:\xampp2\htdocs\barcodeprinting\test\printbarcode.bat');
shell_exec('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /b START C:\xampp2\htdocs\barcodeprinting\test\printbarcode.bat');


$command = "C:\xampp2\htdocs\barcodeprinting\test\printbarcode.bat";
pclose(popen("start /B ". $command, "r"));
```

And still no luck of fixing this.

I'm using XAMPP 1.8.2 using an admin account Windows XP I already check the 
interact with computer in services.msc of Apache.

I don't know what to do I'm stuck here. Please help me thanks!

Comment: try with 'exec' instead of 'shell_exec'